# How do we ignore <body scroll="no"> in MS webbrowser control

Tags: html, scroll, document-body

**Problem we are trying to solve is:** The vertical scroll bar is intentionally disabled in HTML code (by others), but users with larger Monitor screens are setting display to be larger than 100% in Windows causes clickable elements to be outside the the display of the webbrowser control when those pages are opened.

We need a way to reactivate the scroll bars when this occurs.

We have no control or authorship over the web page being opened.

Even though we have scroll bars enabled for the webbrowser control, the only thing we have seen so far that might explain why there is no vertical scrollbars displayed is the Body line at the top of each page. that says:

```
<body id="BuildingSelect.asp" topmargin="0" scroll="no">
```

**My question is:**
Is there a way to tell the MS webbrowser control to ignore the 'no scroll bars' command coming from the web page itself?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using javascript. Try adding the following code before the closure of the body.

```
<script>document.body.removeAttribute("scroll");</script>
```